# Configuration related issue while implementing pyejabberd message system

Tags: python, ejabberd, ejabberd-module, ejabberd-api, ejabberd-hooks

I am implementing a message system in my python app and to achieve this I am using the client library of ejabberd which is pyejabberd. I have checked the official documentation of this to configure the ejabberd.yml file but getting some errors. which is BadStatusLine("") error. IDK why this is getting my ejabberd.yml file's content/configuration is -

```
###              ejabberd configuration file
###
### The parameters used in this configuration file are explained at
###
###       https://docs.ejabberd.im/admin/configuration
###
### The configuration file is written in YAML.
### *******************************************************
### *******           !!! WARNING !!!               *******
### *******     YAML IS INDENTATION SENSITIVE       *******
### ******* MAKE SURE YOU INDENT SECTIONS CORRECTLY *******
### *******************************************************
### Refer to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YAML for the brief description.
###

hosts:
  - localhost

loglevel: 4
log_rotate_size: 10485760
log_rotate_date: ""
log_rotate_count: 1
log_rate_limit: 100

certfiles:
  - /home/ejabberd/conf/server.pem

ca_file: "/home/ejabberd/conf/cacert.pem"

## When using let's encrypt to generate certificates
##certfiles:
##  - /etc/letsencrypt/live/localhost/fullchain.pem
##  - /etc/letsencrypt/live/localhost/privkey.pem
##
##ca_file: "/etc/letsencrypt/live/localhost/fullchain.pem"

listen:
  -
    port: 5222
    ip: "::"
    module: ejabberd_c2s
    max_stanza_size: 262144
    shaper: c2s_shaper
    access: c2s
    starttls_required: true
  -
    port: 5269
    ip: "::"
    module: ejabberd_s2s_in
    max_stanza_size: 524288
  -
    port: 5443
    ip: "::"
    module: ejabberd_http
    tls: true
    request_handlers:
      # /: ejabberd_web_admin
      /: mod_http_api
      "/bosh": mod_bosh
      "/captcha": ejabberd_captcha
      "/upload": mod_http_upload
      "/ws": ejabberd_http_ws
      "/oauth": ejabberd_oauth
    web_admin: true
    http_bind: true
    captcha: false
  -
    port: 5180
    ip: "::"
    module: ejabberd_http
    request_handlers:
      /: ejabberd_web_admin
  -
    port: 1883
    ip: "::"
    module: mod_mqtt
    backlog: 1000
  ##
  ## https://docs.ejabberd.im/admin/configuration/#stun-and-turn
  ## ejabberd_stun: Handles STUN Binding requests
  ##
  ##-
  ##  port: 3478
  ##  ip: "0.0.0.0"
  ##  transport: udp
  ##  module: ejabberd_stun
  ##  use_turn: true
  ##  turn_ip: "{{ IP }}"
  ##  auth_type: user
  ##  auth_realm: "example.com"
  ##-
  ##  port: 3478
  ##  ip: "0.0.0.0"
  ##  module: ejabberd_stun
  ##  use_turn: true
  ##  turn_ip: "{{ IP }}"
  ##  auth_type: user
  ##  auth_realm: "example.com"
  ##- 
  ##  port: 5349
  ##  ip: "0.0.0.0"
  ##  module: ejabberd_stun
  ##  certfile: "/home/ejabberd/conf/server.pem"
  ##  tls: true
  ##  use_turn: true
  ##  turn_ip: "{{ IP }}"
  ##  auth_type: user
  ##  auth_realm: "example.com"
  ##
  ## https://docs.ejabberd.im/admin/configuration/#sip
  ## To handle SIP (VOIP) requests:
  ##
  ##-
  ##  port: 5060
  ##  ip: "0.0.0.0"
  ##  transport: udp
  ##  module: ejabberd_sip
  ##-
  ##  port: 5060
  ##  ip: "0.0.0.0"
  ##  module: ejabberd_sip
  ##-
  ##  port: 5061
  ##  ip: "0.0.0.0"
  ##  module: ejabberd_sip
  ##  tls: true

s2s_use_starttls: optional

acl:
  local:
    user_regexp: ""
  loopback:
    ip:
      - 127.0.0.0/8
      - ::1/128
      - ::FFFF:127.0.0.1/128
  admin:
    user:
      - "admin@localhost"

access_rules:
  local:
    allow: local
  c2s:
    deny: blocked
    allow: all
  announce:
    allow: admin
  configure:
    allow: admin
  muc_create:
    allow: local
  pubsub_createnode:
    allow: local
  trusted_network:
    allow: loopback

api_permissions:
  "console commands":
    from:
      - ejabberd_ctl
    who: all
    what: "*"
  "admin access":
    who:
      access:
        allow:
          acl: loopback
          acl: admin
      oauth:
        scope: "ejabberd:admin"
        access:
          allow:
            acl: loopback
            acl: admin
    what:
      - "*"
      - "!stop"
      - "!start"
  "public commands":
    who:
      ip: 127.0.0.1/8
    what:
      - status
      - connected_users_number

shaper:
  normal: 1000
  fast: 50000

shaper_rules:
  max_user_sessions: 10
  max_user_offline_messages:
    5000: admin
    100: all
  c2s_shaper:
    none: admin
    normal: all
  s2s_shaper: fast

max_fsm_queue: 10000

acme:
   contact: "mailto:example-admin@example.com"
   ca_url: "https://acme-staging-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory"

modules:
  mod_adhoc: {}
  mod_admin_extra: {}
  mod_announce:
    access: announce
  mod_avatar: {}
  mod_blocking: {}
  mod_bosh: {}
  mod_caps: {}
  mod_carboncopy: {}
  mod_client_state: {}
  mod_configure: {}
  mod_disco: {}
  mod_fail2ban: {}
  mod_http_api: {}
  mod_http_upload:
    put_url: https://@HOST@:5443/upload
  mod_last: {}
  mod_mam:
    ## Mnesia is limited to 2GB, better to use an SQL backend
    ## For small servers SQLite is a good fit and is very easy
    ## to configure. Uncomment this when you have SQL configured:
    ## db_type: sql
    assume_mam_usage: true
    default: never
  mod_mqtt: {}
  mod_muc:
    access:
      - allow
    access_admin:
      - allow: admin
    access_create: muc_create
    access_persistent: muc_create
    access_mam:
      - allow
    default_room_options:
      allow_subscription: true  # enable MucSub
      mam: false
  mod_muc_admin: {}
  mod_offline:
    access_max_user_messages: max_user_offline_messages
  mod_ping: {}
  mod_privacy: {}
  mod_private: {}
  mod_proxy65:
    access: local
    max_connections: 5
  mod_pubsub:
    access_createnode: pubsub_createnode
    plugins:
      - flat
      - pep
    force_node_config:
      ## Avoid buggy clients to make their bookmarks public
      storage:bookmarks:
        access_model: whitelist
  mod_push: {}
  mod_push_keepalive: {}
  mod_register:
    ## Only accept registration requests from the "trusted"
    ## network (see access_rules section above).
    ## Think twice before enabling registration from any
    ## address. See the Jabber SPAM Manifesto for details:
    ## https://github.com/ge0rg/jabber-spam-fighting-manifesto
    ip_access: trusted_network
  mod_roster:
    versioning: true
  mod_sip: {}
  mod_s2s_dialback: {}
  mod_shared_roster: {}
  mod_stream_mgmt:
    resend_on_timeout: if_offline
  mod_vcard: {}
  mod_vcard_xupdate: {}
  mod_version:
    show_os: false

### Local Variables:
### mode: yaml
### End:
### vim: set filetype=yaml tabstop=8
```

Am I doing some mistake here or is my configuration wrong? Could you suggest me some way to resolve this issue.

My python script code:

```
from pyejabberd import EjabberdAPIClient
import http
import logging
import json

# Create a client and authenticate with elevated user 'bob@example.com'
client = EjabberdAPIClient(host='127.0.0.1', port=5443, username='admin@localhost', password='yatish@1234', user_domain='example.com',
                           protocol='http')
try:
    client.echo(json.dumps({"test":"sentence"}))
except http.client.BadStatusLine as e:
    # import pdb
    # pdb.set_trace()
    print(">>>>>>>>",e)
```

When I call the method `client.echo` it encouters an exception and throws an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disclaimer: I never used pyejabberd, so I'll just give you some ideas to investigate.

I see your client attempts to connect to port 5443 with HTTP protocol. Looking at your ejabberd configuration, that has TLS enabled... so maybe it should be HTTPS? Or you can try to set "tls: false" in ejabberd.

Also, what kind of connection method does pyejabberd use to connect to ejabberd? XMPP (port 5222), or XMPP over BOSH (port 5443), or XMPP over WebSocket (port 5443, but a different URL path).

Maybe you should set in pyejabberd port 5222 and protocol xmpp, or something like that.

Check in ejabberd log files, if it receives the connection attempt. Try to login with a well-known XMPP client, so you learn how that looks in ejabberd log files (what messages it shows when login is successful), and compare that with your client.